# Insert if no data is found and update if data is found - Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert, invoice

I'm going crazy, this is my code

```
public function add_remito()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $data = array(
            'id_cliente' => $post['id_cliente'],
            'razonsocial_cliente' => $post['nombre_cliente'],
            'fecha_remito'  => $post['fecha'],
            'total_remito'  => $post['total_remito']
        );
    $this->db->insert('remitosclientes', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    if ($id > 0) {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($post['nombre_producto']);$i++) {
            $data1 = array(
              'id_factura' => $id,
              'id_product' => $post['id_producto'][$i],
              'nombre_producto' => $post['nombre_producto'][$i],
              'cantidad' => $post['stock'][$i],
              'precio' => $post['precio'][$i],
              'color' => $post['color'][$i],
              'talle' => $post['talle'][$i]
              );
            $this->db->insert('detalleremitos', $data1);

            if ($this->db->insert_id()) {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where('id_producto', $post['id_producto'][$i]);
                $query = $this->db->get('productos');
                $row = $query->row();
                $quantity_in_stock = $row->stock;

                $new_quantity_in_stock = intval($quantity_in_stock) - intval($post['stock']);

                $this->db->where('id_producto', $post['id_producto'][$i]);
                $this->db->update('productos', array('stock' => $new_quantity_in_stock ));
            }

            $data2 = array(
                        'id_reg_producto' => $post['id_producto'][$i],
                        'reg_nombre_producto' => $post['nombre_producto'][$i],
                        'reg_cantidad_ant' => $quantity_in_stock,
                        'reg_cantidad' => $new_quantity_in_stock,
                        'reg_fecha' => $post['fecha'],
                        'reg_motivo' => "Venta"
                    );

            $this->db->insert('regstocks', $data2);
        }

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Data Save Successfully.');
        return redirect('venta/remitos');
    }
}

public function update_remito()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();

    $idremito = $this->uri->segment('3');

    $data = array(
          'id_cliente' => $post['id_cliente'],
          'razonsocial_cliente' => $post['nombre_cliente'],
          'fecha_remito'  => $post['fecha'],
          'total_remito'  => $post['total_remito']
      );

    $this->db->where('id_remito', $idremito);
    $this->db->update('remitosclientes', $data);

    $q = $this->db->select('id_factura')->get('detalleremitos')->result_array();

    $db_id=array();
    $update=array();

    foreach ($q as $key => $value) {
        $db_id[$key]=$value['id_factura'];
    }

    for ($i=0;$i<count($post['id_producto']);$i++) {
        $update = array(
      'id_factura' => $idremito,
      'id_producto' => $post['id_producto'][$i],
      'nombre_producto' => $post['nombre_producto'][$i],
      'cantidad' => $post['stock'][$i],
      'precio' => $post['precio'][$i],
      'color' => $post['color'][$i],
      'talle' => $post['talle'][$i]
      );

        $update_query = $this->db->where_in('id_factura', $idremito)
         ->get('detalleremitos')->result  ();
        var_dump($update_query);
        if (count($update_query) > 0) {
          $this->db->insert('detalleremitos', $update);//update if ids exist

        } else {
            $this->db->update('detalleremitos', $update, $idremito);//insert if does not exist
        }
    }
}
```

To add the invoice I have no problems, what I can not make it work is to update that invoice, if products were added or details changed, any ideas? Thank you very much <3

https://github.com/outthesystem/facturacion-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

your `update_batch()` function doesn't know what to update, because you forgot to

define a key. It could look like this (depending which ID you need to use):

```
$this->db->update_batch($update, 'detalleremitos', 'id_factura');
```

more about updating data: [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

**edit:**

you further need to take the `$this->db->update_batch()` function out of the `for` loop

and

in your for loop you just need to add to the array `$update`, which at the moment you are overwriting each time the loop increments. More about adding data to arrays [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I'm having the error

"Message: Call to a member function result_array() on array"


I can not find the error

Comment: take the `$this->db->update_batch()` function out of the `for` loop

Comment: Please review those links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049652/update-a-row-but-insert-if-row-doesnt-exist-in-codeigniter

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223752/codeigniter-insert-if-not-exist-and-update-if-not/35223951

Comment: Thanks for the help, I follow his steps but I can not get out of the error: "Message: Call to a member function num_rows () on array" I feel stupid, sorry for so much trouble, but I would appreciate very much to be able to find the solution

Comment: https://github.com/outthesystem/facturacion-codeigniter/blob/master/application/modules/venta/controllers/Venta.php

Comment: you are close, in your `for loop` you just need to add to the array `$update`, which at the moment you are overwriting each time the loop increments, more here `http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php`

Comment: Guys, thanks for everything! Now insert and update works! What is wrong now is that instead of updating or inserting does both :(, how can I make the condition work?

Comment: Use your last comment to create a new question, it is too broad to understand: what is not working, where does it occur, what are the error messages, etc. I've updated the answer to reflect on your comments.