# How to insert only one record in the database on multiple clicks on submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a form and fields are `Name, Email, Mobile no, Message`.

I am able to submit the data in the database using AJAX. There is no issue with AJAX.

Now What I did, I fill the form and click on submit button twice then I check my database and I found the same records twice because of two clicks. If I click three times on the submit button then I am getting same records three times in the database.

Is there any way to stop this issue. Like one click should work on submit button till the data submitting in the database?

**View**

```
<div class="i_p_aboutTeam_alert" id="popup_verify-1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="profile_content">
    <div class="profile_header clearfix">
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close_popup " onclick="closePopup();"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
      </div>
   <div class="profile_body">
      <div class="form_heading">
      <h2>CONTACT FORM</h2>
   </div>
      <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form" autocomplete="off">
         <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
            <label for="name" class="ffl-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
            <label for="mobileno" class="ffl-label">Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="mobileno" class="form-control" id="mobileno">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
            <label for="email" class="ffl-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">

         </div>
           <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
            <label for="message" class="ffl-label">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group text-center">
         <input type="submit" name="send" class="i_btn i_btn_bg  i_btn_round w_100p" value="Submit">
      </div>
      </form>
   </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      lettersonly: true
    },
    mobileno: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //form.submit();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('Home_control/contact');?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#popup_verify-1").hide();
        $("#popup_success-1").show();
      },
    }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function contact() {
  $this -> form_validation -> set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

  $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
  $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('mobileno', 'Mobile no', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
  $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email');
  $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');

  if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
    //$this->index();
  } else {
    $form_data = array(
      'name' => $this -> input -> post('name', TRUE),
      'mobileno' => $this -> input -> post('mobileno', TRUE),
      'email' => $this -> input -> post('email', TRUE),
      'message' => $this -> input -> post('message', TRUE)
      );
    $success = $this -> db -> insert('form', $form_data);
    echo json_encode(array("data" => $success)); // return to the ajax
  }

}
```

Comment: there are two ways. 1. Disable the submit button after first click 2. Check for existing data in table first if present exit if not insert.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223752/codeigniter-insert-if-not-exist-and-update-if-not/35223951#35223951

Comment: @urfusion, I think the first option is the right way. The second option is not good for me because after some time if the user wants to insert the same record then it will not accept but I need it.

Comment: I have to use the code             // $(this).find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);   but where I have to use this code can help me?

Answer (score 0):

maintain flag for request in progress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isReqInprogress = false;
  $("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      lettersonly: true
    },
    mobileno: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //form.submit();
    if(isReqInprogress){
      return;
    }
    isReqInprogress = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('Home_control/contact');?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#popup_verify-1").hide();
        $("#popup_success-1").show();
        isReqInprogress = false;
      },
    }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: give me time to check

Comment: your code is working. can you help me without ajax as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the AJAX code that you can use:

**Solution 1:** If you want to disable the submit button click until AJAX call is complete.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Home_control/contact');?>",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() { 
      $('#form').find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', true); // disable button
    },
    success:function(data){ 
      $("#popup_verify-1").hide();
      $("#popup_success-1").show();
      $('#form').find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', false); // enable button
    }
  });
```

**Solution 2:** If you don't want to disable the submit button but prevent AJAX call from being used multiple times.

```
$("#form").validate({
var isCurrentReqInprogress = false;
...
...

submitHandler: function(form) {
    //form.submit();
    if(isCurrentReqInprogress){
      return;
    }
    isCurrentReqInprogress = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('Home_control/contact');?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#popup_verify-1").hide();
        $("#popup_success-1").show();
        isCurrentReqInprogress = false;
      },
    }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but not working. I mean disabled class not working on submit button

Comment: Please try updated solution or try giving an id (suggested submit_btn) to submit button and then use `$('#submit_btn').prop('disabled', false/true);`