# Using Codeigniter's Model - issue with saving according to primary key

Tags: php, codeigniter, save, insert-update, codeigniter-4

I have been looking for a solution that would replicate MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in my Codeigniter model, which led me to the `save()` function.

I get the logic of it, and my script works fine... but for UPDATING only.

What I've realised now is that my data array is formed from info pulled from an external datafeed, and includes both new AND existing products. There will ALWAYS be a `sku` (primary key) included in for every product, therefore the `save` function will ALWAYS look to update the corresponding row in my database - but never insert it - hence, no new objects are ever added to my database - only updated.

```
// Defined as a model property
$primaryKey = 'sku';

// Does an insert()
$data = [
    'brand' => 'Heinz',
    'name'    => 'Baked Beans'
];

$userModel->save($data);

// Performs an update, since the primary key, 'sku', is found.
$data = [
    'sku'       => xrt567ycr,
    'brand' => 'Heinz',
    'title'    => 'Baked Beans'
];
$userModel->save($data);
```

What is the easiest way to get around this and have the script either insert or update based on whether the `sku` is actually present in the database already or not? All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do an `INSERT () ... VALUES () ... ON DUPLICATE KEYS ....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter insert if not exist and update if not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223752/codeigniter-insert-if-not-exist-and-update-if-not)

Comment: Have you tried using $userModel->replace($data).  https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Comment: [@TimBrownlaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857384/timbrownlaw) I’ve looked into replace() function - but I’ve noticed it replaces the entire row - whereas I only want to replace the columns within the array in the row itself. Would I be able to specify that only certain columns are ‘replaced’ with replace() function- and not entire row - do you know?

Comment: The link @cssBlaster21895 posted is in fact the answer to this question. There is no single method that will make that decision, you have to put in the footwork yourself. Either check it explicitly like that answer says, or you can use the Query Builder method `ignore()` to perform an `INSERT OR IGNORE` for that SKU before calling an `update()`. This ensures that SKU is always present in the DB before the `update()` call occurs.

Comment: Thank you all! Got a bit confused when the codeigniter Documentation mentioned using set() with replace() (but it doesn’t work).